# I want to set image behind form in HTML and CSS without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to set the image behind the form and half part of the image is not shown if I'm using position property is not set properly. Can anyone help me how to fix it?

I'm adding both screenshots of how it looks [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR9bx.png) and how I want to set [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9JHF.png)

Comment: I would do that with position absolute, z-index higher than form's one and try top, bottom, left, right to get the perfect position.

Comment: Please show relevant code. If we don't know the structure of your HTML any answer will just be a guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which should help you on how to put code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: relative` to place your element exactly. Additionally, your below element must have higher z-index than under element

Answer (score 0):

Follow This Example.

```html
<!Doctype Html>  
<Html>     
<Head>      
<Title>     
Add the Background image!   
</Title>  
</Head>  
<Body background="Picture.jpg">  
</Body>  
</Html>
```